# Getting error from server and show it on client

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, devextreme

In a form built with `html` and `javascript` how can I send value to **server** and if the value is incorrect then get **validation error** from **server** and send them to **client(show in form)**.
I am using `asp.net mvc` and `devextreme` component but it is still showing error in client side .

```
dataField: "Route",
editorType: "dxSelectBox",
validationRules: [{
    type: "required",
    message: "is required" // fill this error message from server 
}],
colSpan: 2,
editorOptions: { items:temp},
```

I am using `asp.net mvc` and `devextreme` component.

Comment: I think you should ignore the validation in client side. Send all data to server and validate it in server. Then you can send what you want to client.

Comment: Is there any example to show me how can i do it? @Duannx

Comment: Hmm. Hard to show you an example. You are using a javascript library to validate your form right?

Comment: I am using devexterme components . And jquery.

Comment: Have you using `dxValidator` component to show message? Which control do you want to validate with?

Comment: I use dxform and in every items i have some dxselectbox and dxtextbox that i define validate : true for every dxtextbox and dxselectbox

Comment: DevExtreme have a validated event. It is fired after an editor value is validated against the specified validation rules. Send data to your server in this event.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the modelstate error to view, Devextreme version 17.1.4+ handles it for you. just pass modelstate like this:

```
if(...)
{
  ModelState.AddModelError("Mobile","Mobile is not valid!");
  return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

**Mobile** is your ViewModel property which Devextreme form has a data filed for it.